# com.amazonaws.services.gluejobexecutor.model.VersionMismatchException

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

Exactly like in this [AWS forum question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=931931) I was running 2 Jobs concurrently. The Job was configured with `Max concurrency: 10` but when executing `job.commit()` I receive this error message:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job.commit.
: com.amazonaws.services.gluejobexecutor.model.VersionMismatchException: 
Continuation update failed due to version mismatch. Expected version 6 but found version 7
(Service: AWSGlueJobExecutor; Status Code: 400; Error Code: VersionMismatchException; Request ID: 123)
```

The two Jobs read different portions of data.

But I can't understand what's the problem here and how to deal with it. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 6):

The default JobName for your bookmark is the glue `JOB_NAME`, but it doesn't have to be.

Consider you have a glue job called `JobA` which executes concurrently taking different input parameters. You have two concurrent executions with input parameter `contextName`. Let's call the value passed into this parameter `contextA` and `contextB`.

The default initialisation in your pyspark script is:

`Job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)`

but you can change this to be unique for your execution context. Instead:

`Job.init(args['JOB_NAME']+args['contextName'], args)`

This is unique for each concurrent execution so would never clash. When you view the bookmark state from the cli for this job, you'd need to view it like this:

`aws glue get-job-bookmark --job-name "jobAcontextA"`

or

`aws glue get-job-bookmark --job-name "jobAcontextB"`

You wouldn't be able to use the UI to pause or reset the bookmark, you'd need to do it programatically.

Comment: haven't tested it yet but seems a good solution to deal with such problem, +1

Answer (score 3):

Reporting @bgiannini's answer in this other [AWS forum question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=937893&tstart=0), it looks like that the "version" was referring to job bookmarking.

If multiple instances of the same job are running simultaneously (i.e. max concurrency > 1) and using bookmarks, when job run 1 runs job.init() it gets a version and job.commit() seems to expect a certain value (+1 to version for every job.commit that is executed I guess?). If job run 2 started at the same time and got the same initial version from job.init(), then submits job.commit() before job 1 does, job 1 doesn't increment to the version it expected to.

Actually I was running the 2 Jobs with `Job bookmark: Enable`. Indeed when **disabling bookmarking**, looks to be working for me.

I understand it might not be the best solution but it can be a good compromise.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you, I now understand what's happening. However, the problem remains.